# How to do custom filtering in Datatables with comma separated values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am using Datatables to display table data in my JSP page. I have enabled search functionality in my datatable.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1rde0nbm/4/)

I want to allow the user to use "," (comma separated values) in the search box and want the comma's to be treated or OR. I have tried to implement it but as soon as i enter "," things don't work. What change should i do in order to achieve the required functionality

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {

   var search = $('.dataTables_filter input').val().toLowerCase();
   var inputArray=search.split(",");

   var node = table.cell({ column: 0, row: dataIndex }).nodes().to$();

   var text = node.find('b').text();
   text += node.find('[name$=locationId] option:selected').text()
   text += node.find('[name$=empRole] option:selected').text();


   for(var i=0;i<inputArray.length;i++){
   return text.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputArray[i])>-1;
   }

return false;

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTables seems to stop calling `search()` internally if all rows is filtered out (there is probably other reasons). I could achieve the functionality by turning `off()` all bindings and trigger the filter programmatically; if you have a custom filter you can invoke it by `draw()` :

```
initComplete: function() {
  $('.dataTables_filter input').off().on('keyup', function(e) {
    table.draw()
  })
}
```

This also give the possibility to filter only when the user hits <kbd>enter</kbd> :

```
if (e.which == 13) table.draw()
```

Then only return true *if* there is a match, and a sanity check is also a good idea:  `obama,` will give two indexes in the array, and everything matches an empty string :

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
   var search = $('.dataTables_filter input').val().toLowerCase().split(',');
   var node = table.cell({ column: 0, row: dataIndex }).nodes().to$();

   var text = node.find('b').text();
   text += node.find('[name$=locationId] option:selected').text()
   text += node.find('[name$=empRole] option:selected').text();
     text = text.toLowerCase();

   for (var i=0, l=search.length; i<l; i++) {
     if (search[i].trim() != '' && text.indexOf(search[i]) >-1) return true
   }
   return false;
})
```

Not sure if this is the brightest solution; or if it works as expected in your real life scenario, but at least it return correct rows for `obama,`, `obama, trump`, `trump, obama`, `obama, test` etc.

updated fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/1rde0nbm/16/**

Comment: Home with the flu and fever; major blunders may occur ;)

Comment: take care , i will handle some if any ;)